# Can't refer to GeoFire in iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, geofire

I'm new here and also new to iOS and Swift development.

I'm trying to use GeoFire for my first project and install the library using Cocopod. I can see the GeoFire files in my project directory. However, I am having problem referencing it in my ViewController.

```
var geofire: GeoFire?
```

The above always result in the error "use of declared type 'GeoFire'", what is the install step that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you're using Swift. [Geofire's README file mentions](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc):

> Using GeoFire with Swift
>
> GeoFire supports Swift out of the box! In order to use GeoFire and
>   Swift from CocoaPods, add the **use_frameworks!** line to your **Podfile**,
>   like so:

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'GeoFire', '>= 1.1'
```

Did you do that? Remember to run `pod install` after you modify your `Podfile` if it needs modifying.

Did you also add `import GeoFire` at the top of the view controller where you want to use it?

Comment: Thanks! I did not run 'pod install' after making changes to my Podfile and also did not include 'import GeoFire' at the top of the VC (most tutorials didn't do that too...). Thanks again!

Comment: Check _Install_ and _Get started_ from [here](https://cocoapods.org/). Next time you'll know all the steps. You're welcome! :)